# Sending Multicast Packets from Docker Container (to multicast group)

Tags: networking, docker, udp, multicast

I have an application that sends messages over UDP multicast that I've been attempting to put under docker. I've been running into much headwind trying to send multicast packets from a docker container.

I have been able to send messages through the `--net=host` option on running the docker container. I would, however, like to stick with a bridge configuration.

I would like to get some insight in what needs to be done in order to publish messages through the standard docker bridge configuration. I'm attempting to publish messages on `239.9.60.250` with port `16000`. I have tried publishing udp port `16000` through the following argument on `docker run`.

```
-P 0.0.0.0:16000:16000/udp
```

This doesn't give me any change in behavior and my host doesn't see any multicast traffic.

Comment: I have a similar issue and wonder if something changed since may 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker network drivers have no IGMP/PIM support, so you should really establish a direct Layer 2 connection from the container to the physical switch/router.

As you have found out yourself, docker's default bridge network will not help you here.

I haven't tested it with multicast, but you should be able to achieve that with [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).

[macvlan driver](http://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-bridge-mode-configuration) should help you with your problem, but is currently experimental as of Docker Engine 1.11