# Recieve UDP multicast packets inside docker container without using "--net host" option

Tags: docker, networking, udp, multicast

Is there any way to achieve this? I can't use "--net host" since i need more containers to run in the same host and map ports with the host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I publish a UDP Port on Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596409/how-do-i-publish-a-udp-port-on-docker)

Comment: That solution doesn't work for multicast udp traffic, so far I only made it work with --net host which is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

This is followed by your own [`moby/libnetwork` issue 2397](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/issues/2397), which just received (oct. 2021) the update:

> Multicast to/from a docker bridge network is currently not possible.
>
> This is due to limitations with how linux kernels provide support for multicast routing.
> Packets are forwarded to the docker bridge using iptables and the unicast routing table, but multicast packets are handled differently in linux kernels.
>
> A workaround is to run a tool like **[smcrouted](https://github.com/troglobit/smcroute)** on the host (or in a container with access to the host network).
> This process does the work of managing the linux multicast forwarding cache.
>
> Side note: If running `docker swarm`, and all your multicast communication is happening between nodes you can control, you could use **[weave net](https://www.weave.works/oss/net/)**, which apparently has support for multicast.
>
> It would be nice if we could see some multicast support added here... but ultimately it feels like more of a kernel issue.

[This suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37467039/6309)  a [macvlan bridge](http://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-bridge-mode-configuration), a way to bridge the container into a physical network.
There is also [IPVlan driver](https://git.ustc.edu.cn/tlyrics/moby/-/blob/e9e3ab6b6a718118a5928e726ab1297f0b8ef5cd/experimental/vlan-networks.md), still [experimental 4 years later](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35767), and [the feedbacks](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21735#issuecomment-205586894) are still ongoing.